# JSON to database with variable length lists

Tags: mysql, json

I'm looking to store recipes in a database. I know how I would make JSON out of them:

```
recipe = {
name:"",
preheat: {
    temp: x,
    unit: ""
},
time:{
    prep: x,
    cook: y,
    rest: z,
},
ingredients:[
    {
        name: "",
        amount: x,
        unit: ""
    },...
],
instructions:[
    "",
]
}
```

I'm not sure how I would make an SQL database out of it due to the two lists, the ingredients and the instructions, as they both could be of any length. I know that if there was one list that could be any length, I would put the items vertically and put the list at the end but with 2 I'm not sure.

Comment: Please make sure that the samples (code, json, etc..) is more or less correct. The above is not something I can relate to any language I know of (it is not even JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize your data, however, but that is a job, not doable in one answer.
You can also take advantage of the Standard SQL JSON data type provided by MySQL (and others).

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html

Using MySQL 8.0, you can store the whole JSON document in to a field, and start querying. Heck, you can even index data from the JSON itself to make look-ups faster.

Assuming you have the following JSON document set as MySQL variable (complete recipe of Waffles is proprietary!):

```sql
SET @doc = '{
  "name": "Traditional Belgian Waffles",
  "preheat": {},
  "time": {
    "prep": "25 min",
    "cook": "2 min per waffle",
    "rest": "1 hour"
  },
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "flour",
      "amount": "500",
      "unit": "g"
    },
    {
      "name": "melted butter",
      "amount": "200",
      "unit": "g"
    },
    {
      "name": "egg",
      "amount": "4",
      "unit": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "yeast",
      "amount": "20",
      "unit": "g"
    }
  ],
  "instructions": [
    "Flour into a bowl and add egg yolks, milk, melted butter, ...",
    "Best eat while hot!"
  ]
}';
```

Creating the table, and inserting the data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE recipes(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, doc JSON, PRIMARY KEY (id));
INSERT INTO recipes (doc) VALUES (@doc);
```

Now you can start querying:

```sql
SELECT doc->>'$.name', doc->>'$.ingredients' FROM recipes;
```

And now for something **really** fancy:

```sql
SELECT nr, CONCAT(amount, unit, " ", name) as ingredient FROM recipes AS r JOIN
    JSON_TABLE(r.doc->>'$.ingredients', '$[*]' COLUMNS(
        nr FOR ORDINALITY,
        name VARCHAR(60) PATH "$.name",
        amount VARCHAR(10) PATH "$.amount",
        unit VARCHAR(5) PATH "$.unit"
        )) AS ingredients;
```

Result:

```
+------+--------------------+
| nr   | ingredient         |
+------+--------------------+
|    1 | 500g flour         |
|    2 | 200g melted butter |
|    3 | 4 egg              |
|    4 | 20g yeast          |
+------+--------------------+
```

The advantage is that you can do `SELECT doc FROM recipes`, and you have the whole JSON in your favorite programming language. All at once.